# AngularJS databinding to complex objects through $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a restful service that returns an order.  This order has a list of items.  I'm making the screen where you can edit a specific item from an order.  so I need to have the list of items before I can find and display the info for the specific item.  I'm solving it like this:

```
$scope.order = orderResource.get({id:$routeParams.orderId}, function(order) {
    $scope.item = _.findWhere(order.items, {id:$routeParams.itemId});
});
```

And the binding looks like this:

```
<input id="itemName" type="text" ng-model="item.name">
```

My question is: is this the best way to solve this problem?  (I don't want to use a route with a resolve.)

Comment: I don't think there's a "best way" for solving such a localized and specific problem. So my question for you is: Does your solution fullfils your requirements?

Comment: I think the question actually applies to a broader base of situations than just this specific example.  The code above is resorting to using another library (underscoreJs) to try to filter and find the needed data.  This feels like something that would come up often in larger applications and I am also curious if there is a better way to do this with AngularJS.

Comment: @JimCooper actually sounds more like data structure sent from API needs to be mapped to fit UI. Obviously using `undescore` is a convenience but still not difficult using native script or using `angular.forEach` to loop over data to map to new array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should make an endpoint that will return a specific item. An example GET endpoint could be

`/orders/:id/items/:itemId`

```
$scope.item = orderResource.get({id:$routeParams.orderId, itemId: $routeParams.itemId});
```

If that is not possible what you are doing seems fine.